# MySQL View, get result from stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, view

I would like to create a view on MySQL, and the content will be read from stored procedure, is that a way to make it?

Which mean when I exec "mystoredProcedure()" I will receive a list of result, can I use view table to exec it, so result will directly show on view table.

Please advice me if you have any other solution.

Appreciate your help.

Thank you

Comment: A view can only contain a SQL `SELECT` query, not a `CALL` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. The syntax of `CREATE VIEW` requires a `SELECT` statement, but a stored procedure is executed with a `CALL` statement.

Comment: how about get stored procedure result from sql function? is that possible?

Comment: No, a function can only return one value, not multiple rows or columns.

Comment: ok, thank for you help, if u have others way to make it, may be u can share it to me. thank you

Comment: If I could think of anything I would have put it in the answer. I really don't think it's possible in any way.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the stored procedure, you can do something like this inside the procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpData (id int PRIMARY KEY, name varchar(50)) ENGINE=MEMORY;
```

then insert the data you want to return.

When you want to use the result or even join it somewhere, just `call ABC`, after that then you can reference the tmpData table.

Note: temporary tables are visible only in your session, it will not interfere with others, but it's a good idea to name them as unique as possible so it will not hide any real tables with the same name. I always use tmp prefix.